# Access files using path in UBUNTU

Tags: python, file, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, path

I was trying to make a chess game on vs code after watching a tutorial on youtube. VS code throws an error saying, FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: '/home/phalit/Documents/PYTHON/CHESS-AI/src/images/imgs=80px/black_rook.png'.

Once before also i couldnt access a file using its path, can someone help me?

```
import os

class Piece:

    def __init__(self,name,color,value,texture=None,texture_rect=None):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        if color=='white':
            value_sign = 1
        else:
            value_sign = -1
        self.value = value*value_sign
        self.texture = texture
        self.set_texture()
        self.texture_rect = texture_rect

    def set_texture(self,size=80):
        self.texture=os.path.join(
        f'/home/phalit/Documents/PYTHON/CHESS-AI/src/images/imgs={size}px/{self.color}_{self.name}.png')

    def add_moves(self,move):
        self.moves.append(move)
class Pawn(Piece):

    def __init__(self,color):
        if color == 'white':
            self.dir = -1
        else:
            self.dir = +1
        super().__init__('pawn',color,1,0)
class Knight(Piece): 
     def init(self,color): super().init('knight',color,3.0)

class Bishop(Piece): def init(self,color): super().init('bishop',color,3.001)

class Rook(Piece): def init(self,color): super().init('rook',color,5.0)

class Queen(Piece): def init(self,color): super().init('queen',color,9.0)

class King(Piece): def init(self,color): super().init('king',color,10000.0)
```

Comment: is `imgs=80px` a valid and existing folder name?

Comment: @RandomDavis valid in Linux and its typical filesystems: yes, existing: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Is this the right path? If not, what is the right path?

Comment: i was following this tutorial btw https://youtu.be/OpL0Gcfn4B4

Comment: the error pops up about after an hour FOR ME, not the guy doing it

Comment: @habibigaju if you actually answered the questions we asked, maybe we could've solved this for you by now...I'm not sure why you would ask help, and then specifically ignore the questions of people trying to help you. Do you even want help?

Comment: In a terminal run `find ~ -name 'black_rook.png'` and compare the result with the path in the exception.

Comment: BROO THANKS I FOUND IT, random davis. It wasnt imgs=80px, there was a hyphen in between.